# Let $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n \}$ be a sample. Why can one subtract $L$ from every sample value $x_i$ to get equivalent results?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Suppose we have a sample $\{x_1, \ldots ,x_n\}$ obtained from i.i.d RV's  $X_i\sim N$ (normal). Then in books on statistics, depending on the values obtained, they subtract a fixed quantity $L$ from every $x_i$, to get smaller values for computations, resulting in the sample $\{x_1 - L, \ldots, x_n -L\}$. The books states that this has no influence on statistical descisions based on the sample (why?).

Below I've attached a picture from a practical case (using SAS), where the sample consist of values $x_i \approx \pm 40$. Since the sample values $x_i$ are close to $40$ the book has decided to substract $40$ from all $x_i$. The variable **diameter** is the original values, while the variable **diam_40** are the values with $40$ subtracted from them. Indeed the computed values seems pretty similar, however $t$ values are different also $Pr >$.

[image]

Why can we subtract from every sample value without getting different results "later on" ? How can I show my descisions will always be the same regardless of having subtracted or not ?

Answer (score 1):

The $t$ values are calculated for two different hypotheses. The hypothesis test carried out is
$$
\frac{\bar{x}-\mu^{H_0}}{\sqrt{\hat{V}(\bar{x})}}.
$$
The null value is $\mu^{H_0}=0$ in both cases. But a null value of $0$ in the second case is equivalent to a null of $40$ in the first equation! Let $\bar{z}=\bar{x}-40$ be the transformed mean. The variance is unaffected. The first test in the output is
$$
\frac{\bar{x}}{\sqrt{\hat{V}(\bar{x})}}.
$$
and the second is
$$
\frac{\bar{z}}{\sqrt{\hat{V}(\bar{z})}}=\frac{\bar{x}-40}{\sqrt{\hat{V}(\bar{x})}}
$$
which is really the test in my first equation but with the null hypothesis $\mu=40$.

Comment: Ohh, so the difference $Pr > |t|$ corresponds to that in one test we are actually calculating with $\mu^{H_0} = 0$ and in the other, due to subtraction, we are calculating with $\mu^{H_0} = 40$. In general can one subtract a value $L$ from a sample and then do statistical inference using $F, X^2, t$-tests and get the same results ? I mean could we go from model to model and get same results using the adjusted sample ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen Yes, otherwise it would be a bad test. You're just scaling it. For example, it shouldn't matter if you have temperature measurements in Celsius or Fahrenheit.

Comment: When you say bad test, does you refer to every of the test I've just mentioned or only the $t$-test ?

Comment: Are all tests immune to scaling ?